# How can I select a box which has specific text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this HTML:

```
<h5>something</h5>
<ul>
   <li class="name">John</li>
   <li class="age">21</li>
</ul>
<h5>specific text</h5>
<ul>
   <li class="name">Peter</li>
   <li class="age">19</li>
</ul>
<h5>something else</h5>
<ul>
   <li class="name">Ali</li>
   <li class="age">62</li>
</ul>
```

I want to select this part:

```
<h5>specific text</h5>
<ul>
   <li class="name">Peter</li>
   <li class="age">19</li>
</ul>
```

The logic is the content of `<h5>` tag. I want the one which is `specific text`. Actually expected result is an array of both that name and that age. Some thing like this: `var res = ['Peter', 19];`.

But my code selects all those `<ul>`s:

```
$('ul').map(function (){
   var res = [$(this).find('li.name').text(), $(this).find('li.age').text()];
});
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `:contains()` to find the `H5` that contains the specific string you want. Then use `.next()` to get that `ul` associated with the `h5`

```js
$("h5:contains('specific text')").next('ul').map(function (){
   var res = [$(this).find('li.name').text(), $(this).find('li.age').text()];
   console.log(res)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h5>something</h5>
<ul>
   <li class="name">John</li>
   <li class="age">21</li>
</ul>
<h5>specific text</h5>
<ul>
   <li class="name">Peter</li>
   <li class="age">19</li>
</ul>
<h5>something else</h5>
<ul>
   <li class="name">Ali</li>
   <li class="age">62</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Jquery script for getting data from ul list :

```js
$('ul').map(function (){
   var res = [$(this).find('li.name').text(), $(this).find('li.age').text()];
  // console.log(res);
   
});
var htmVal = '';
$('h5').each(function(index){
htmVal = $(this).html();
if(htmVal == 'something else'){
var detail ={name:$(this).next().find('li.name').html(),age:$(this).next().find('li.age').html()};
console.log(detail);
}

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h5>something</h5>
<ul>
   <li class="name">John</li>
   <li class="age">21</li>
</ul>
<h5>specific text</h5>
<ul>
   <li class="name">Peter</li>
   <li class="age">19</li>
</ul>
<h5>something else</h5>
<ul>
   <li class="name">Ali</li>
   <li class="age">62</li>
</ul>
```